# Slick - Parameters are ignored in a Query Template

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, parameters, slick

I'm trying to write a query template for like so:

```
val byIdentifier = for {
  (identifier, issuer) <- Parameters[(String, String)]
  o <- Objects if (o.identifier === identifier) && (o.identifierIssuer === issuer)
} yield o
```

And then use it like this:

```
def findByIdentifier(id: String, issuer: String): Option[Object] = 
  byIdentifier(id, issuer).firstOption
```

`Objects` is a Table with lifted embedding:

```
case class Object(val identifer: String, val identifierIssuer: String)

object Objects extends Table[Object]("objects") {
  def identifier = column[String]("identifier")
  def identifierIssuer = column[String]("identifier_issuer")
  ...
}
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that `findByIdentifier("asdf", "weqr")` produces a query with a `where` clause that is just `false`:

```
select ... from "objects" where false
```

What am I missing in my query template to have proper querying?

Comment: This may or may not make a difference. Have you tried using `is` instead of `===` in the filter conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following syntax:

```
val byIdentifier = for {
  (identifier, issuer) <- Parameters[(String, String)]
  o <- Objects
  if o.identifier === identifier
  if o.identifierIssuer === issuer
} yield o
```

I often find that slick can be a bit wonky with its syntax, and the current documentation isn't particularly good.

You could also make your `findByIdentifier` do the work:

```
def findByIdentifier(id: String, issuer: String): Option[Object] = {
    Query(Object).where(_.identifier === id).where(_.identifierIssuer === issuer).run.headOption
}
```

I hope that helps...